# React header doesn't fill screen

Tags: html, css, reactjs, header, react-bootstrap

I'm new to React and don't really understand why my code will not fill the screen horizontally.

If I open the page then this it what is shown for the header:
[image]

However for some reason it is also possible to scroll to the side so it will look like:
[image]

Which doesn't look that great. What have is wrong and how can it be fixed?

Header.jsx

```
function Header(){ 

  return (
  <Navbar className="navbar-container" bg="dark" variant="dark" expand="lg">
    <Navbar.Brand href="https://github.com/">
      <img src={logo} alt="logo" style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
      </Navbar.Brand>
    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
    <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav" className="navbar-collapse">
      <Nav.Link href="home">Home</Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link href="projects" >Projects</Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link href="settings" >Settings</Nav.Link>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
    <Navbar.Text lg="6" className="d-none d-lg-block">Daily progress:</Navbar.Text>
    <ProgressBar bgcolor="#6a1b9a" completed="60"/>
  </Navbar>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

Header.css

```
.navbar-container {
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
}
```

I thought adding "width:100%" to the navbar-container would fix it, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: Try using `max-width: 100%` instead of just `width`.

Comment: I tried but it didn't help unfortunately @Ollie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are scrolling the page, not the header itself.
You better check the other elements, since they might overflow.

If you checked other elements:
Really depends on what other styles are added to the element, but you can try:

`max-width: 100%;` as [Ollie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13138080/ollie) said, but keep in mind the box model:

```
.navbar-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Or you can hide the overflow:

```
.navbar-container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden; // if necessary
}
```